# Why is this controller undefined?

Tags: angularjs

first time posting here. Trying to learn some angular by making a tabs script, I'm following
exactly what is described in code controller but the script won't run.

I'm getting this error, saying my controller is undefined : Error: [ng:areq]

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="tabModule">
<head>
   <link href="Stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="tab" ng-controller="TabController as useTab">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li ng-class="{active: useTab.isTab(1)}">
                <a href ng-click="useTab.setTab(1)">FirstTab</a>
            </li>
            <li ng-class="{active: useTab.isTab(2)}">
                <a href ng-click="useTab.setTab(2)">SecondTab</a>
            </li>
            <li ng-class="{active: useTab.isTab(3)}">
                <a href ng-click="useTab.setTab(3)">Third Tab</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="panel" ng-show="useTab.isTab(1)">
            <h4>Description</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel" ng-show="useTab.isTab(2)">
            <h4>MoreDescription</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel" ng-show="useTab.isTab(3)">
            <h4>ExtraDescription</h4>
            <p>Test</p>
       </div>
    </section>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/TabScript.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/Angular-js-route.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is my attempt at a controller:

```
var app = angular.module('tabModule', []);
app.controller('TabContoller', function() {
    this.tab = 1;
    this.setTab = function(tabSelected) {
        this.tab = tabSelected;

    };
    this.isTab = function(checkTab) {
        return this.tab === checkTab;
    };
});
```

I'm trying to find out if the tutorials on code school are out of date or something, I was so happy to find them, but with something this basic not working, I'm wondering if I'm wasting my time. Thank you everyone!

Comment: Check this line `app.controller('TabContoller', function() {`...TabController is spelled wrong.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple typo

Answer (score 0):

1. instead of ng-controller="TabController as useTab" write ng-controller="TabController"
2. instead of writing useTab.isTab and useTab.setTab and so on.... remove the useTab, leave only isTab and setTab

Comment: The controllerAs syntax the asker is using is not the problem.